# loading image without storing it to disk from a servlet with Jquery Asynchronously

Tags: javascript

I want to load an image from a servlet to a jsp file without storing it to any disk with help of jquery .It should be done Asynchronously . Below is my code

JSP.page ( Code of entire JSP  page is not given ) . When the page is loaded GetCaptchaImage() function is called . This function will call doget method in the servlet Captcha. Image should be loaded in the result div. But nothing is been loaded . When I put an alert inside the javascript it shows data in encoded format .I have tried to encode the image in base64 format in servlet but still nothing comes to the browser. Even writing the response to printer object doesn't worked

[data image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z27I6.png)

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function GetCaptchaImage ()
    {

    $.get("Captcha",function(data){
    $('.result').html('<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,' + data + '" />');
    });
    } 


</script>
</head>
<body onload="GetCaptchaImage()">
<div class="result" >
</div>
```

**Servlet code** :

```
@WebServlet("/Captcha")
public class Captcha extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Captcha() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           gtcResult = captcha.GenerateCaptchaCustom(100) // Generates the image

                InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(gtcResult.getbmp());
                BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);


                response.setContentType("image/bmp");




                OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "bmp", out);

                out.flush();
                out.close();







            }
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long duration = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("duration : "+ duration);



    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Image Failed : "+ e.getMessage());
    }


    //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());  
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried inspecting elements to see what the image tag src looks like? also having redundant data:image/bmp;base64,` is possible as most image encoders do it for you, so maybe try running it without that?

Comment: I have tried using that also but it was throwing error. At least after putting base64 it went .

Comment: what error were you getting?/ have you tried to inspect the code and see if the tag is being formed correctly?

Comment: I have tested the code with text data and with a image saved in the disk . it worked correctly for both the cases  . The tags were generated . if I revove Base64  I am Getting the below error   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer.fill(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:566)

Comment: I found something In this URL but is is not working . Not sure if getting image form outputStream through Jquery  asynchronously is possible or not https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/26404099